# How did Sansa come to marry Ramsay?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I am missing an episode in season 5 of *Game of Thrones*. Suddenly, for me, Sansa is married to Ramsay. Why and how did Littlefinger allow this to happen?

Comment: How far have you made it past that episode? Keep watching...

Comment: That's probably several episodes that you're missing.

Comment: watch the episode

Comment: Related: [Isn't Sansa already married?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95350/21267) and [What did Ramsay do to Sansa Stark?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139122/21267)

Answer (score 2):

Littlefinger informs Sansa of Ramsey's proposal in season 5 episode 3, *High Sparrow*.

They are, in fact, already journeying to Winterfell when he tells her the purpose of the trip.  She is naturally horrified by the idea of marrying into the family of traitors that killed what was left of her family and stole her home, but Littlefinger convinces her that this is an opportunity for her to find her strength and that the only way she might possibly avenge her family is to get close to the Boltons.

As for Littlefingers motives, well, its hard to say why he does anything.  He seems here to be trying to build Sansa up into more than a shrinking violet, and angling that into gaining her trust.  While at the same time, this plays the North against Kings Landing yet again, adding to the chaos that he loves to work with.